# Run a simulation several times with different parameters and store values

Tags: excel

Consider a spreadsheet which performs some computations based on a fixed value (in the rxample below, `D3`) and is iterative. E.g.

```
D3: 4

B3: 12 
B4: 58 (=B3*$D$3+10)
B5: 242 (=B4*$D$3+10)
B6: 978 (=B5*$D$3+10)

Total = 1290 (=sum(B2:B5))
```

Now, suppose I wanted to try out different values of `D3` (let's call this `P`) and store the different totals I get, i.e.

```
P    Total
4 1290
5 2252
6 3618
7 5460
```

How would I do this with Excel? A macro? Please note that the above example is a simplified version of the real thing. It should be clear that I need to compute `B3`-`B6` so I can compute the sum.

#### Update:

Each computation requires several columns. E.g. we would use values on `B3,B4, ..`  and `C3,C4, ...` .

Comment: Should not be too hard for you to adapt my suggestion to your needs.

Comment: @Doc: Nope, no problem. I added that for Lavir's answer.

Comment: Although the answers you've already got are fine for this case, Excel also offers some built-in solutions for needs of this type. Look in the help for "scenarios" and "data tables", as part of "what-if analysis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro can do this. If B7 contains the sum formula, try this

```
Sub RunSimulation()
     Dim p as long
     for p = 4 to 7
         Range("D3")=p
         Debug.Print Range("B7")
         Range("L" & (p-1)) = Range("B7").Value
     next
End Sub
```

EDIT: added a line for storing the results, as requested.

If you don't want to enter the sum formula in your sheet, you can calculate the total in VBA either:

```
Dim total as Long 
Dim row as long
total = 0
for row = 2 to 5
    total = total + Range("B" & row)
Next
Debug.Print total
```

(Use `Double` instead of `Long` for `total` if you are dealing with floating point numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done in following manner:

```
    A     B         C         D
1   x     tmp1      tmp2      Total
2   3     $A2+10    $B2*10+10 $C2*$B2   The formulae are just for example.
3   $A2+1 $A3+10    $B3*10+10 $C3*$B3
4   $A3+1 $A4+10    $B4*10+10 $C4*$B4
```

Excel has capabilities to automatically increment indices in formulae.

Comment: +1. I would prefer this solution against mine, if the real sheet is not too complicated, one calculation can be done in one row, one does not have too many different variable input values, and it is ok to have a big sheet with all the intermediate results. Otherwise, a macro may be the better alternative.

Comment: @All: Each calculation needs several columns and rows.

Comment: They can be moved to be in single line. Yes, the resultant code will look like nightmare of Steve McConnell but nobody said that Excel fits for such calculations.

Comment: @Lavir the Whiolet: your suggestion will work with calculations distributed among more than a line. If things are not too complicated, one can build blocks and copy them around the sheet. But I would not do this if things are getting too confusing this way.

Comment: Then, as I said, Excel does not fit for such a task. You should use another tools like MATLAB (or Octave), Mathematica, Ruby...

Comment: @Lavir: in MATLAB, Mathematica or Ruby one will have to write a program, just as I did. MATLAB is preferable if one needs to have a lot of matrix/vector calculations (or existing MATLAB libraries). Mathematica's strength is symbolic math (but that is too simple, Mathematica is a very big software with a lot of other features).